# PrimeNG p-table: in edit mode, can I stay in edit mode if there is an error in validation?

Tags: angular, primeng

**in edit mode, can I stay in edit mode if there is an error in validation?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8lXn.png)

**The current situation is to exit the editing mode. The effect I want is that if there is a problem with the information filled in, it is still in the editing mode，What do I need to do?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJLvd.png)

**html file**

```
<p-table [value]="cars2" dataKey="vin" editMode="row">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Vin</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th style="width:8em"></th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-editing="editing" let-ri="rowIndex">
        <tr [pEditableRow]="rowData">
            <td>
                {{rowData.vin}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.year" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData.year}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
                <button *ngIf="!editing" pButton type="button" pInitEditableRow icon="pi pi-pencil" class="ui-button-info" (click)="onRowEditInit(rowData)"></button>
                <button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" class="ui-button-success" style="margin-right: .5em" (click)="onRowEditSave(rowData)"></button>
                <button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="onRowEditCancel(rowData, ri)"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**ts file**

```
    onRowEditInit(car: Car) {
        this.clonedCars[car.vin] = {...car};
    }

    onRowEditSave(car: Car) {
        if (car.year > 0) {
            delete this.clonedCars[car.vin];
            this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Success', detail:'Car is updated'});
        } else {
            this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary: 'Error', detail:'Year is required'});
        }
    }

    onRowEditCancel(car: Car, index: number) {
        this.cars2[index] = this.clonedCars[car.vin];
        delete this.clonedCars[car.vin];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: You can use set the #dt1 to p:table and use the #dt1.initRowEdit(record);
but ts file use need get dt1 as parameter in event.

Solution 2: You can use   @ViewChild('dt1') grid: Table; in ts file and use it like this.grid.initRowEdit(record);